# CSS dropdown menu lags in Firefox

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have made a pure CSS dropdown menu for my client. The dropdown menu uses a background image behind the main menu items. In Firefox 3 and 4, the CSS menu does NOT have noticeable lag when it is by itself:

[by itself](http://drcarlagreco.com/navtest.php)

In Firefox 3 and 4, when the dropdown menu is placed within my client's website, the hover effect on the menu items has a short lag, and the hover effect "follows" the cursor.

[on website](http://www.drcarlagreco.com/)

What do I have to do to make the dropdown menu on the website perform as fast as when it is by itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is isn't a solution, just a suggestion (but too detailed for a comment)! 
I can't reproduce the issue, as I only have FF7 available, but just in case it's related - your images are all too large.

The relevant example, `pictures2/sandHeader.jpg` - which forms the `background-image` of your `#nav` element - is a whopping 1024 x 768 when you're only displaying a fraction of it. Whether that, in combination with the other CSS3 effects on your page, results in lag when using the menu, I can't be sure. Try cropping it down to size and see if that makes a difference.

And while we're on the subject, all your images are being downsized in the browser - it'd be far better for your bandwith and our loading times if they were only as large as they needed to be.

To see for yourself, right-click any one in FireFox and choose '*View Image Info*'. It'll tell you the actul size and what it's being displayed as.

Comment: I tried cropping down the background image for the navigation. It still didn't work. After I removed the all the box-shadows and text-shadows, the dropdown was much more responsive but the main menu items still lagged.